# Class 'DatabaseRoot' not found in

Tags: php, class, inheritance

```
DBHandler.php

class DatabseRoot {
    public $conn;

    public function __construct() {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
        // opening db connection
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }
}


class UserHandler extends DatabaseRoot{

}
```

But the above extension says `DatabaseRoot` not found, Both these classes are inside the same `DBHandler.php`. If anybody can point out what I am doing wrong that would be great.

Comment: Maybe because `DatabseRoot ` typo ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `DatabseRoot` to `DatabaseRoot`